# getting started on website development on Java

Tags: java, web-deployment

As the title says, I want to start to develop a website based on `java`. I have some experience with `html`, `JavaScript`, `jQuery`, `css`, object oriented languages like(`Java` and `C#`) but I know that is not enough and I don't have a clue where to start from and what should I look for.

As you can see, I am a totally newbie on this.

What is the best choice I have to use as an *IDE*?

Step by step learning resource for java web development?

And some stuff like that.

I have Googled it guys, but I want to know what do you recommend me to.

Comment: This is the right question but in the wrong place, it's far too broad and opinion based for Stack Overflow. Try doing some google searches and try both Netbeans and Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html).  It is about 1/2 way down the page, in the left hand column.

It gives a good general overview of developing a Java based web site, with plenty of additional information about how to wire it to a database, and have the site react dynamically to previous inputs.

It might take some time to do each of the steps; but, it covers a lot of ground.  Walking through the steps might require extra reading at [one of the Java EE Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/).  If the detailed every aspect too finely, the tutorial would never end.

Comment: As an aside, Netbeans might make an excellent IDE if you are going to use their tutorials; however, in reality any IDE (or even a text editor) will do with a little extra work.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found the tutorials at http://www.coreservlets.com/ to be very useful; Start with *Servlets and JSP*, and *Java Server Faces* later.

Answer (score 0):

Just for starters, i'd start with Servlet and JSP.

(1) Eclipse IDE for coding (free)

(2) Tomcat as a web server / servlet container (free)

(3) Tutorial - look for any 'hello world' tutorial on servelts/jsps, one example could be 
http://helloworldprograms.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/servlet-hello-world.html

Once you get the hang of it, look up design/architecture issues such as MVC.
My favorite architecture is clean html pages that issue AJAX requests for a Java servlet (preferably Spring's implementation for REST), but before getting there you need to understand the bare basics of a Servlet.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

What do you want to do? Website development is a broad topic, and there are several different approaches to do this. You can go full out J2EE stack (using something like [Matt Raible's AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) to get started), but given your limited experience I'd recommend playing with some of the new guys on the block. [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) or the [Play framework](http://www.playframework.com/), which are sort of the Java versions of Django, and both have excellent tutorials.

As for IDE, the best is hands down IntelliJ Ultimate Edition. However, if you're on a budget NetBeans or Eclipse are still better than nothing.